# How to calculate call cost with an SQL query for Billing

Tags: mysql, sql, billing

Has anyone or does anyone know how to calculate call charges from a call log table and tariff table in sql and put the output in a new table???

tariff rates for seconds or minutes.

Could you provide some sample queries?

Here is the code that I used to create the table with field names:

```
CREATE TABLE cdr (
accountcode VARCHAR (30),
src VARCHAR(64),
dst VARCHAR(64),
dcontext VARCHAR(32),
clid VARCHAR(32),
channel VARCHAR(32),
dstchannel VARCHAR(32),
lastapp VARCHAR(32),
lastdata VARCHAR(64),
calldate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
answerdate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
hangupdate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
duration INT(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
billsec INT(8) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
disposition VARCHAR(32),
amaflags VARCHAR(128),
PRIMARY KEY (clid,channel,calldate)
);
```

and for the tariff rates, peak and off peak I have:

```
CREATE TABLE tariffs (ratestart TIME, rateend TIME, ratecharged DECIMAL(10,8));

INSERT INTO tariffs(ratestart, rateend, ratecharged)
    VALUES("08:00:00", "19:00:00", 3.3333);
INSERT INTO tariffs(ratestart,rateend,ratecharged)
    VALUES("19:00:00", "08:00:00", 1.5555);
```

I would like to have the output of the cost of the call made into a new table with callerid, Source, Destination, Call duration, tariff and cost of the call.

Also should I create another table with a list of users? And also how would anyone be charged off peak during weekends?

Comment: Hmm. Addition? Subtraction? Some fractions? Really needs more info.

Comment: Can you post the table definitions, some sample data, and the expected output along with an explanation of the algorithm (i.e. 0.10 for the first minute, 0.08 each additional minute based on the `ELAPSED_MINUTES` column in the `CALL_LOG` table.  Multiply the result by `1+TARIFF_PCT` from the `TARIFF` table using the `TARIFF_ID` column in `CALL_LOG` for the join).

Comment: "Could you provide some sample queries." Only if you post some code first, I'll show you mine if you show me yours ;)

Comment: @Pekka - Ive got two tables, one is the call log with call duration, source and destination and some other fields, I have another table with the tariffs, offpeak and peak rates. I want to know how I could query these tables to calculate the call duration with the tariff rates by the minute or seconds which will give me the cost of each call made. and this will be inserted into a new table with the source, destination, callerid , call duration and the cost of the call.

Comment: @Adnan I see. I think it would be best if you could show the actual table structures.

Comment: @Pekka - I just posted the table structure.

Comment: @Tony - Ive posted some code :-D

Comment: @Adnan: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: I really recommend against doing your call charge calculation in SQL. Billing is usually pretty important and deserves a suite of unit tests at the very least. SQL is good at filtering sets, but not very expressive when it comes to complex calculations.

Comment: @Michael Valenty : you can write unit tests in TSQL and for TSQL. There is nothing wrong with performing billing calculations in TSQL 'close' to the data.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat -Im sure I posted a question, Im just confused on how I would query the database to calculate the tables to get the cost of a call, Im a bit of an SQL noob, so thats why im confused on where to start from

Comment: What happens if a call crosses a tariff boundary? A call that's purely within a single tariff is trivial to do in SQL. One that crosses one or more tariff borders would mean some truly ugly SQL.

Comment: @Marc B - What would you suggest that should be used to calculate the call costs?

Answer (score 1):

You should simplify your life by inserting more data in the tariff table:

```
INSERT INTO tariffs(ratestart, rateend, ratecharged)
    VALUES("00:00:00", "08:00:00", 1.5555);
INSERT INTO tariffs(ratestart, rateend, ratecharged)
    VALUES("08:00:00", "19:00:00", 3.3333);
INSERT INTO tariffs(ratestart, rateend, ratecharged)
    VALUES("19:00:00", "24:00:00", 1.5555);
```

This makes it a bit simpler to handle calls by separating the early morning and late night rates.  (You might need to use '23:59:59' in place of '24:00:00' if you can't store midnight like that, but then you need to adjust the other end times to 1 second before the transition, and you modify queries to use '`<= rateend`' instead of '`< rateend`'.)

Do you have to worry about calls that overlap two tariff periods?  What about calls that last more than a whole tariff period?  More than 24 hours?

You should also translate terms you use.  For example, you request:

> with callerid, Source, Destination, Call duration, tariff and cost of the call

- CallerID ⟶ `clid`
- Source ⟶ `src`
- Destination ⟶ `dst`
- Call duration ⟶ `duration`
- Tariff ⟶ `ratecharged`

What units are used to measure call duration?  Is the charging regime simply the rate that applied when the call started, so someone calling at 07:59:59 for 12 hours gets to talk at the night rate?  How does call duration differ from billing seconds?  Should the calculation use billing seconds?

You might also like to look at a previous question that was very similar to this one:

- [Calculating different tariff-periods for a call in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585645/calculating-different-tariff-periods-for-a-call-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Jonathan - I do not know how I would calculate the cost of call if call is made during an offpeak and carries over to peak rate, also call duration differs from billing seconds like the call duration is where when a user enters a number and calls it, it includes ringing which should not charge a user, but billing seconds is when someone Answers the phone and then Hangsup, That's the seconds that should be charged.

Comment: @Jonathan - Also I should add that I am creating an application which will query the database and display the table with the cost of calls in C#.

Comment: @Adnan: life, unfortunately, is complex.  You'll need to think about the issues I raised.  The use of C# is completely coincidental; the use of any specific DBMS is largely coincidental.  You will need to deal with the issues raised in the abstract, understanding how long calls that span changes in tariff rates will be handled.  This is doubly important when you get to handling different rates for weekends; then your tariff table will include 'day of week' information too.

Comment: @Adnan: Presumably, your application will have to look at `answerdate` rather than `calldate` to determine the tariff at the start of the call.  You may have to section a single call record into multiple billing records, or sum multiple component 'rate × duration' values into a single number for a single call.  The most common case will sum one such number; the general case might need to sum many such numbers.

Comment: Hmm. A slight improvement on your first attempt at this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545480/calculate-costs-of-call-in-sql-database-from-cdr) but still, to be honest, you are trying to get the community to write it for you.

Comment: @liamf: is your comment aimed at me, or at @adnan?  Placed as a comment to my answer, it appears to be addressed to me; its content, though, is applicable to @adnan.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Sorry for ambiguity. As you point out (and as was my intention), applicable to @adnan.